# How to use and update NativeScript ListView

Tags: nativescript

I am trying to figure out how to use NativeScript's ListView and I can not figure out how. I have yet to find any good tutorials and really need help. I need to be able to show and update (add and subtract items from) a ListView in NativeScript. Thanks in advance!

Comment: what do you mean by `tables`? Could you please post the code that is what you have done?

Comment: @DinhLe Sorry, I meant ListeView. I have edited my question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can mostly find all the things about the ListView [here](https://docs.nativescript.org/cookbook/ui/list-view) but I will make a demonstration of ListView practice that I'm using in my app. I'm using MVC structurce so we will have `page.xml`, `page.js` and `page-viewmodel.js`. In `page.xml`, we will want to have a listview with like this:

```
<Page>
 <ListView items="{{ myItems }}" loadMoreItems="loadMore">
    <ListView.itemTemplate>
       <Label text="{{ message }}" textWrap="true" />
    </ListView.itemTemplate>
 </ListView>
</Page>
```

The `<ListView.itemTemplate>` is where you define a prototype for an item of data array. You can use a normal array but I suggest using built-in class called `ObservableArray` for programmatically changing of any item or any property later on.

In the model, which is `page-viewmodel.ts`, we have:

```
var Observable = require("data/observable").Observable;
var ObservableArray = require("data/observable-array").ObservableArray;

public class PageViewModel extends Observable {
    private _myItems = new ObservableArray<MyItem>()

    get myItems(): {
        return this._myItems
    }

    public loadItems() {
        var dataArray = ["Red", "Blue", "Green"];
        for (var i in dataArray) {
            var item = MyItem(dataArray[i])
            this._myItems.push(item);
        }
    }
}
var pageViewModel = new PageViewModel();


public class MyItem extends Observable {
    public message: String;

    constructor(value) {
        this.message = value;
    }
}
```

Finally, in the controller which is `page.ts`:

```
import {pageViewModel} from "./page-viewmodel"

exports function pageLoaded(args) {
    var page = args.object;
    page.bindingContext = pageViewModel
}

exports function loadMore(args) {
    pageViewModel.loadItems();
}
```

In conclusion, you define the ListView as well as its prototype in XML. After that, the `viewmodel` (which is an Observable object) is where you handle the data(add item, delete item, load items from backend, etc). Finally, you import that `viewmodel` to the controller(page.js) and bind to `page.bindingContext` so that the `XML` can receive the data

P/S: I'm writing this in TypeScript. In Javascript, the implementation is basically the same, there are just a bit of difference in the syntax. For example here is how the `page.js` would look like:

```
var pageViewModel = require("./page-viewmodel");

function pageLoaded(args) {
    var page = args.object;
    page.bindingContext = pageViewModel
}
exports.pageLoaded = pageLoaded;
```

Comment: Could you also include how to do it in javascript?

Comment: it's almost the same. It's just different little from some syntax that I just updated in `P/s`